# Nexus5 is using ldpi PhoneGap Build Icon

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing couple apps using PhoneGap Build and just realize their icons are displaying really bad on my Nexus5. I put a small colored dot on each icon file to see what file exactly my phone is using and discovered that its is using the LDPI file.

Why the Nexus5 would use the LDPI icon instead of HDPI?

Here is my XML config

```
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Nexus 5 is considered as xxhdpi..
What if you try not to define the exact icon for each dpi and see what it does. I think each device can recognise by itself the drawable folder suitable for it and thus select the appropriate icon.

Comment: If I remove them all, the app uses the PhoneGap icon. I tried removing just LDPI/MDPI and it worked(it used the XDPI them). But now I put the LDPI/MDPI again to do a test and it still using the XDPI.

Comment: Did you try to create an xxhdpi folder?
The closest to Nexus 5 drawable folder is xhdpi, maybe this is why it uses this folder to get the needed resources.

Comment: it have already not a folder but an xxdpi file in the icons folder. Its not on folder for each resolution but one for each platform (ex ios, android, blackberry, etc) and one file for each platform inside.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to remove the LDPI and MDPI lines from the config.xml

looks like it is getting always the minimun resolution available instead the tha maximum supported, as any decent device nowadays is HDPI, I  believe its not a big problem.

On my case it displayed well the HDPI icon on iPhone4, iPhone5S, Nexus5, Nexus7 and Galaxy S4